# How do I make jquery function activate on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

So, right now this is set to be activated on click. I keep trying to mess with the code to get it to just activate immediately and get rid of clicking entirely, but nothing's been working for me.... Pls help.

```
$(function () {



  $(".item").onload(function () {
    $(this)
      .next().toggleClass("active");
  });

  $("#body").css("min-height", "100%");


});
```

Comment: Replace the whole `$('.item').onload(...)` with `$(".item").next().toggleClass('active');`

Comment: This works, but it skips the animation where the object slides out that happened when I had it set to onclick

Comment: Ah try this `setTimeout(function() { $(".item").next().toggleClass('active'); },100);`

Answer (score 0):

write $('item').load(function(){
});

and if that doesnt work make a normal function and put the function on the onload attribute of item element.

Answer (score 0):

Make jquery trigger event for you:

```
$(function() {

    $(".item").click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggleClass("active");
    }).trigger('click');

    $("#body").css("min-height", "100%");

});
```